# How to limit both total number of Quartz jobs and number running on single node in a cluster

Tags: grails, cluster-computing, quartz-scheduler

If I have a 3 node cluster.  I need to run a specific Quartz job as follows:

- There is at a given time, many (say 30) of these jobs that need to be run.
- Limit the number of a that Quartz job running on all clusters combined at the same time (to 10, because of system resources)
- Limit the number of a that Quartz job running on a single server at the same time (to 5, because of CPU load)

How do I limit both the total number of simultaneous job instances to 10, and the number running on any one host to 5?  Is this even possible?

Note that I cannot limit the number of threads as I have other jobs that need to run on the same servers at the same time, and those need threads as well.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that I found the answer.

The answer is to run two (or more) separate Quartz schedulers.  A job in the first scheduler would schedule the job for the second scheduler, and the second would run them.  The second scheduler could then be limited to (in this case) 5 threads, although the first scheduler could have more.

Some information about this can be found in
http://quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.2.x/cookbook/MultipleSchedulers

However I do not know how to implement two separate Quartz Schedulers in Grails.  If anyone could help with that I would appreciate it.  There is an existing Stack Overflow question about this though, although it is unanswered.

Answer (score 1):

While not exactly limiting the consecutive job count, you can limit the maximum thread count with the thread pool configuration. See [Quartz Configuration Reference](http://quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.2.x/configuration/ConfigThreadPool).

The Grails Quartz plugin comes with a handy script for installing the config file:
`grails install-quartz-config`

> **org.quartz.threadPool.threadCount**
>
> Can be any positive integer, although you should realize that only
>   numbers between 1 and 100 are very practical. This is the number of
>   threads that are available for concurrent execution of jobs. If you
>   only have a few jobs that fire a few times a day, then 1 thread is
>   plenty! If you have tens of thousands of jobs, with many firing every
>   minute, then you probably want a thread count more like 50 or 100
>   (this highly depends on the nature of the work that your jobs perform,
>   and your systems resources!).

Comment: The problem with this (as I mentioned in the question) is that this is not the only job that needs to be run.  If I limit the threads to 5, that limits it for all jobs.  I just want to limit one job to 5 parallel executions, while leaving other threads available for other jobs.